# Unknown column in field list MariaDB

Tags: mysql, database-design, mariadb, stored-procedures, parameter

I am using PHPMyAdmin and MariaDB and get this weird error as mentioned in the title.

```
CALL log_total_outstanding(@message);
MySQL said: Documentation

#1054 - Unknown column 'time' in 'field list'
```

I have read online this issue can be due to using "" instead of '' or due to whitespace but i have neither of these issues. I also don't have a column called 'time' anywhere.

Code:

```
USE bank;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS total_outstanding_log;
CREATE TABLE total_outstanding_log (
    total_outstanding DECIMAL(13,2) NOT NULL,
    log_time DATETIME NOT NULL
);

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE IF NOT EXISTS insert_total_outstanding_log(
         IN total DECIMAL(13,2),
         OUT reply VARCHAR(50)) 
BEGIN
    
    INSERT INTO total_outstanding_log (total_outstanding,log_time)
           VALUES(total, CURRENT_DATE); -- Insert into log table
    SET REPLY = 'Total outstanding log inserted successfully '
            || CHAR(CURRENT_DATE); -- Set the out param message

END $$
DELIMITER ;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE IF NOT EXISTS log_total_outstanding(OUT message VARCHAR(50)) 
BEGIN
    
    -- DECLARE @total_outstanding DECIMAL(13,2);
                -- Used to store total outstanding amount
    
    SELECT
        SUM(a.opening_balance)
        +
        (SELECT SUM(amount)
        FROM transaction WHERE isIncoming)
        -
        (SELECT SUM(Amount)
        FROM transaction WHERE isOutgoing) AS total_outstanding
        INTO @total_outstanding -- Assign the value to declared variable
    FROM account a;
    
    -- Call inserting log procedure (nested)
    CALL insert_total_outstanding_log(@total_outstanding, message);

END $$
DELIMITER ;

CALL log_total_outstanding(@message);
SELECT @message; -- Display total oustanding log message
```

The

```
SELECT
        SUM(a.opening_balance)
        +
        (SELECT SUM(amount)
        FROM transaction WHERE isIncoming)
        -
        (SELECT SUM(Amount)
        FROM transaction WHERE isOutgoing) AS total_outstanding
        INTO @total_outstanding -- Assign the value to declared variable
    FROM account a;
```

Does work alone I have tested.

Comment: "create if not exists".  Are you sure the procedures in the database correspond to what you show?  Eg. select into  @ total_outstanding while the declare  @ total_outstanding is commented out.

Comment: Do you have any triggers?

Comment: @BillKarwin nope

Comment: I don't see any reference to an identifier `time` in the code you posted. I guess the error is not coming from this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`||` is not for string concatenation in MySQL/MariaDB.  Use the `CONCAT(..., ...)` function.  Here is what MySQL says:

```
mysql> select 'Total outstanding log inserted successfully '             || CHAR(CURRENT_DATE);
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 'Total outstanding log inserted successfully '             || CHAR(CURRENT_DATE) |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                                0 |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 3 warnings (0.00 sec)

mysql> show warnings
    -> ;
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                                                               |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1287 | '|| as a synonym for OR' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use OR instead |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'Total outstanding log inserted successfully '                      |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '\x014\x88\xCE'                                                     |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks this fixed it also dropping my procedure